# SSDT installation issue (Failed to execute EXE package.)

Tags: visual-studio-2017, sql-server-data-tools, failed-installation

I am having an issue with the SSDT installation for VS2017.

I have ran the installer three times, once basic, once following VS update and the last following some minor windows updates.

All 3 times the logs stumble at the same point, anyone know what this .exe it is trying to run is (I am running the installer with Admin...). I read somewhere for a similar error that it might be the SDK but I am able to run this locally, any nice workarounds to having this installed out there?

```
[29BC:A138][2017-09-26T09:28:00]i000: MainViewModel.OnPackageActionProgress: Percent completed: 50, Overall progress: 4
[1EC4:6DB0][2017-09-26T09:28:00]e000: Error 0x800703e9: Process returned error: 0x3e9
[1EC4:6DB0][2017-09-26T09:28:00]e000: Error 0x800703e9: Failed to execute EXE package.
[29BC:A138][2017-09-26T09:28:00]e000: Error 0x800703e9: Failed to configure per-machine EXE package.
[29BC:A138][2017-09-26T09:28:00]i000: MainViewModel.OnPackageAction: Install Completed for package SQL Server Analysis Services (id: Microsoft.DataTools.AnalysisServices)
[29BC:A138][2017-09-26T09:28:00]i319: Applied execute package: Microsoft.DataTools.AnalysisServices, result: 0x800703e9, restart: None
[29BC:A138][2017-09-26T09:28:00]e000: Error 0x800703e9: Failed to execute EXE package.
[1EC4:6DB0][2017-09-26T09:28:00]i351: Removing cached package: Microsoft.DataTools.AnalysisServices, from path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\9864EE5369359DB622D0234B6C6B7640B949140C\
[29BC:A138][2017-09-26T09:28:00]i000: MainViewModel.OnPackageActionProgress: Percent completed: 100, Overall progress: 100
[1EC4:6DB0][2017-09-26T09:28:00]i372: Session end, registration key: SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{5d5d6235-5c8c-4377-9a75-1b6368850657}, resume: None, restart: None, disable resume: No
[1EC4:6DB0][2017-09-26T09:28:00]i330: Removed bundle dependency provider: {5d5d6235-5c8c-4377-9a75-1b6368850657}
[1EC4:6DB0][2017-09-26T09:28:00]i352: Removing cached bundle: {5d5d6235-5c8c-4377-9a75-1b6368850657}, from path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{5d5d6235-5c8c-4377-9a75-1b6368850657}\
[1EC4:6DB0][2017-09-26T09:28:00]i371: Updating session, registration key: SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{5d5d6235-5c8c-4377-9a75-1b6368850657}, resume: None, restart initiated: No, disable resume: No
[29BC:A138][2017-09-26T09:28:00]e000: MainViewModel.OnBundleAction: Bundle action failed: Recursion too deep; the stack overflowed (0x800703E9)
[29BC:A138][2017-09-26T09:28:00]i399: Apply complete, result: 0x800703e9, restart: None, ba requested restart:  No
[29BC:6724][2017-09-26T09:28:04]i000: MainViewModel.OpenUrl: Opening url: C:\Users\RTOMPS~1\AppData\Local\Temp\SsdtSetup\SSDT-Setup-ENU_20170926092556.log
```

Answer (score 73, accepted):

The answer from Nick is very helpful, but I still failed at `SSDT-Setup-ENU.exe /repair` with the same error `Error 0x800703e9: Failed to execute EXE package.`.

Then I tried it with a very straightforward way: (Disable UserAccountControl first)

1. copy `SSDT-Setup-ENU.exe` to `c:\temp` and execute `SSDT-Setup-ENU.exe /layout` to download a local copy of the bundle.
2. open `C:\temp\redist` and double click `NDP461-KB3102438-Web.exe`
3. open `C:\temp\payload` and double click `vsta_setup.exe`
4. repeat to install others...

[image: C:\temp\payload directory listing]

Comment: Thanks for returning and documenting your solution. They've really messed this product up.... for years now.

Comment: This answer is pure gold. How did you ever figure this out?

Comment: This needs more upvotes!! I found that my install was failing on the "send data to Microsoft" which I NEVER agreed to on the original VS install. Microsoft was trying to install it behind the scenes with vsta_setup.exe.

Comment: It is too late but may help others. After this, go to Tools>Extensions and Update, install Microsoft Rdlc Report Designer for Visual Studio.

Comment: What is #4 referring to? I only see \redist and \payload folders. Inside "\payload" folder, in addition to vsta_setup.exe, I see a bunch of .msi files. Is this what #4 refers to? After vsta_setup.exe finishes, click each .msi in this folder?

Comment: Don't worry about the order of step #4. The most important thing is to find wich package is not working correctly. So run every package one after an other and when you hit an error, try to repair/uninstall/reboot. Then restart process and hope :-) (It worked for me!)

Comment: I tried to install SSDT 2017 at least 20 times and about 10 different ways and nothing worked.  I tried your solution and it actually worked! Thank you Nick and Daniel.  SSDT2017 should NOT be this difficult to install.

Comment: I had to completely uninstall Visual Studio 2017 SSDT first and delete the leftovers  in  "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio" before running the installer again. Repair/Modify did not work.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/troubleshooting-installation-issues#step-3---delete-the-visual-studio-installer-directory-to-fix-upgrade-problems

Comment: For me that still didnt work. But continuing the idea, i installed Microsoft.DataTools.AnalysisServices.VSIX Microsoft.DataTools.IntegrationServices.VSIX Microsoft.DataTools.ReportingServices.VSIX 
manually, and finally everthing is installed.

Comment: This failed because I did not have full administrative access through my own login. I had some proxy install rights, but not full. Maybe that's why this is failing for so many? If you are installing on a network computer, you may need your IT dept to do this for you. I was running into all the same errors. But when I let my network admin do it for me, it ran without a hitch.

Comment: For me, none of the above fixed my issue. As it turns out, a single CPU core will prevent installation with the same symptoms as above (apparently the single processor HAL is not supported by the SSDT installer, while the multiprocessor HAL is required for installation). Anyway, in case you happen to need to install this on a single-core VM like I did, add at least one more CPU core for the duration of the installation and then remove it once everything's installed. I'm adding this here because this wasted an entire day of my time.

Comment: I follows these steps and installed packages successfully. Where can I find SSDT\Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.SqlTasks.targets? It is not under C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio.

Comment: In my environment, the issue had to do with elevated (admin) privileges being restricted.  I followed this process and then opened a command prompt in elevated mode.  I was then able to run all of the installers successfully from the command line.  THANK YOU for this answer!

Answer (score 16):

This is the most likely link I came to when I got the same message in my log:

```
Applying execute package: Microsoft.DataTools.AnalysisServices, action: Install, path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\9864EE5369359DB622D0234B6C6B7640B949140C\VSIXBootstrapper.exe, arguments: '"C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\9864EE5369359DB622D0234B6C6B7640B949140C\VSIXBootstrapper.exe" /q /admin /instanceIds:"fc3f0e2c" /logFile:"C:\Users\a_nzchuk\AppData\Local\Temp\SsdtSetup\SSDT-Setup-ENU_20171205113839_002_Microsoft.DataTools.AnalysisServices.log" "payload\Microsoft.DataTools.AnalysisServices.vsix"' 
MainViewModel.OnPackageActionProgress: Percent completed: 50, Overall progress: 17 
MainViewModel.OnPackageActionProgress: Percent completed: 50, Overall progress: 17 
........... 
...
Error 0x800707d3: Process returned error: 0x7d3
Error 0x800707d3: Failed to execute EXE package.
Error 0x800707d3: Failed to configure per-machine EXE package.
MainViewModel.OnPackageAction: Install Completed for package SQL Server Analysis Services (id: Microsoft.DataTools.AnalysisServices)
Applied execute package: Microsoft.DataTools.AnalysisServices, result: 0x800707d3, restart: None
```

So I'll document my findings here.

In my start menu I had *Visual Studio 2017 (SSDT)*. It ran OK but didn't have any BI projects available

This is what I did from an Administrator elevated command prompt:

1. Copied `SSDT-Setup-ENU.exe` into *C:\temp* (rather than a user specific download folder which the admin user may not have access to)
2. Ran `SSDT-Setup-ENU.exe /layout` to pre-download support and redist files (this was after a required restart)
3. Ran `SSDT-Setup-ENU.exe /repair` to try and repair the install. It gave me a button *Repair* that I clicked.
4. Ran `SSDT-Setup-ENU.exe /repair` again. Selected *Modify*. Noted that only *SQL Server Database* was ticked, but none of the others (SSAS, SSIS, SSRS)
5. Ticked *SQL Server Analysis Services* and pressed Modify. It proceeded to do it. Got stuck at 50% for a few minutes but eventually worked
6. Repeated for *SQL Server Reporting Services* and *SQL Server Integration Services*

After this, when I reran VS2017, it had the BI projects and allowed me to create a 1400 SSAS solution

Comment: I am at another client today and _AGAIN_ I cannot install this ridiculous thing

Comment: The was very helpful but was still getting an error.  Poking around I found C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\vs_installershell.exe and ran it.  It came up with a nice gui showing my install status saying that I needed to reboot the computer to finish the install.  After reboot I ran it again and it showed no error, so I continued with Nick's instructions and then all worked well.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid I followed the steps mentioned by you and I could finally see BI template in my VS2017. I did restart after every repair.Instead of modifying one after another, I selected SSAS, SSIS & SSRS all at a time, clicked Modify, it worked. Thanks a lot. After struggling for a day, I could install successfully.

Comment: .. and another client last week - same issue - it sits there for ages then gives up. It never installs first time

Comment: I had to do as Jeff Leach and run the vs_installershell.exe and then follow Nick's instructions. Thanks

Comment: Today I tried to install on a brand new laptop (with SSMS 17 installed beforehand) and I the installer failed with "Seems you have installed a previous version of SSAS or SSRS extension that is incompatible with the version to be installed"

Comment: This time around, it somehow installed Analysis Services OK but would not install the others (SSIS, SSRS) by using repair. So I ran each of the VSIX files in the downloaded layout and that has added the project type as required

Answer (score 6):

Previous failed installations left VS2017 recognising that the installation was present in Visual Studio Installer. I removed the installation, restarted and the re-install was successful...

Answer (score 2):

For SSDT for VS2018, Version 15.5.2
same failed at execute exe. only do
1. SSDT-Setup-ENU.exe /layout 
2. SSDT-Setup-ENU.exe /repair (tick SSAS/SSRS/SSIS based on your requirement)

and this already works. I think MS also do some job for this.

Comment: These steps were sufficient for me, too, with VS2017 15.7.3 and SSDT 15.1.61804.210 with SSIS selected. Based on suggestions in other answers, I ran the commands from an administrator command prompt. I do not know if that was necessary. For the record, the error code I got was slightly different – 0x800703F6 – but in all other respects, the symptoms were identical. I had previously tried to install several times with restarts in-between and from different networks.

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: This might **not** be relevant any more since [SSDT 15.8.2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt?view=sql-server-2017) is now out.

---

In my case, I was on VS 2017 15.7.2 and I can't complete the installation in SSDT 15.6. What I did was to install SSDT 2017 15.7.0 and it worked.

Make sure to uninstall previous SSDT installations via the VS installer or Control Panel also the **Microsoft Reporting Services Projects** and **Microsoft Aanalysis Services Projects** extensions first if you have them before launching the installer.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** I think my Python issue is a subset of Jeff Leach's comment about repairing Visual Studio. So, I would probably look at any Visual Studio errors you had while installing and try and fix them before trying to install SSDT. For the time being I would NOT update Visual Studio or its installer to the newest versions (15.7 and 1.16) because of known bugs with SSDT 2017. They are working on a fix that will be out with 15.7.2 but it's not out yet.

Info for the edit:

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/246732/ssdt-1560-installer-the-configuration-registry-key.html

---

I found that Daniel's method worked, but I had to install Python manually to be successful.

After successfully installing the .msis in the payload directory I tried to install the Analysis Services VSIX and I wasn't successful because the installer couldn't install Python 3.6.3. I found the page at the bottom and did the following to successfully install the Analysis, Integration, and Reporting VSIXs.

1. Check error logs and find what version of Python is the problem.
2. Manually download and install the proper Python version (my logs said 3.6.3). The name of the executable was python-3.6.3-amd64.exe and I got it from https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.6.3/python-3.6.3-amd64.exe
3. Uninstall SSDT extensions from within Visual Studio. I uninstalled all of my previously unsuccessful VSIXs.
4. Manually install VSIXs. This worked out for me and I am able to use all of the SSDT functionality!

Just to do control testing, I installed Reporting Services with the /repair option and was successful. I think the main issue was the Python error. I think if I would've had Python installed everything would've gone smoothly. This is very frustrating because I got this same Python "error" when first installing Visual Studio 2017 (15.6.7)...expect the "error" was just a caution and didn't prevent me from using Visual Studio. But somehow it prevented the install of SSDT 2017.

I hope none of y'all have to go through this like I did today at work!

Info that helped solve this:

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/98172/packageidcpython3exex64packageactiondownloadpackag-1.html

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error 0x800703e9 installing SSDT with the SSRS option checked. After trying some of the previous good suggestions unsuccessfully, including using the /layout option to download the package locally, I found that the Visual Studio installer portion of the package needed a reboot to finish. After the reboot, I was able to run Microsoft.DataTools.ReportingServices.VSIX successfully.

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar problem with different error code, but the same

> "Failed to execute EXE package problem".

I tried all the solution above to no avail. But, after creating an installation layout out of `SSDT-Setup-ENU.exe` and then trying to execute `vsta_setup.exe` as suggested by Daniel. I get to the underlying error message, it's has something to do with `Android NDK` believe it or not, and since I'm from Syria, any change to these packages should be done through a `VPN` connection. So the **solution** was to run Visual Studio 2017 installation layout, remove all these ugly android packages "Android SDKs and NDKs and even the emulators, yes, a nuclear solution since I don't have a VPN connection", and then run `SSDT-Setup-ENU.exe /repair`. Everything worked just fine.
I hope this might save someone's time after it wasted mine.

Answer (score 1):

My installation came also with a error. I tried the several things mentioned above, but it didn't help. So I was guessing that it could be the disk space of my VirtualBox VM. I made the `C:` drive bigger and that was the trick.
SSDT requiere:
Hard disk space: up to `130 GB` of available space, depending on features installed; typical installations require `20-50 GB` of free space.