# Error when installing SSDT (SQL Server Data Tools)

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2017, ssms, sql-server-data-tools, sql-server-2017

I have a problem during the installation of SQL Server Data Tools for Visual Studio 2017

I get the following error (translated):

```
The requested meta file operation is not supported (0x800707D3)
```

Screenshot: [See here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7PdSd.png)

Log file available here:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/e34kry9ycj76j7n/SSDT-Setup-ENU_20171219090643.log?dl=0

Here's the relevant section from the linked log file:

```
[13C4:3020][2017-12-19T10:07:22]i000: MainViewModel.OnPackageActionProgress: Percent completed: 0, Overall progress: 27
[13C4:3020][2017-12-19T10:07:22]i000: MainViewModel.OnPackageActionProgress: Percent completed: 0, Overall progress: 27
[13C4:3020][2017-12-19T10:07:22]i000: MainViewModel.OnPackageActionProgress: Percent completed: 0, Overall progress: 27
[13C4:3020][2017-12-19T10:07:22]i000: MainViewModel.OnPackageActionProgress: Percent completed: 0, Overall progress: 27
[13C4:3020][2017-12-19T10:08:49]i000: MainViewModel.OnPackageActionProgress: Percent completed: 0, Overall progress: 27
[13C4:3020][2017-12-19T10:08:51]i000: MainViewModel.OnPackageActionProgress: Percent completed: 0, Overall progress: 27
[13C4:3020][2017-12-19T10:08:51]i000: MainViewModel.OnPackageActionProgress: Percent completed: 0, Overall progress: 27
[13C4:3020][2017-12-19T10:08:51]i000: MainViewModel.OnPackageAction: Install Completed for package SQL Server Integration Services 2012 (id: SSISOneDesigner2012)
[13C4:3020][2017-12-19T10:08:51]i319: Applied rollback package: SSISOneDesigner2012, result: 0x0, restart: None
[4214:2830][2017-12-19T10:08:51]i329: Removed package dependency provider: {DB97C76B-9116-42C5-8814-0041856EB9E6}, package: SSISOneDesigner2012
[4214:2830][2017-12-19T10:08:51]i329: Removed package dependency provider: Microsoft.DataTools.ReportingServices, package: Microsoft.DataTools.ReportingServices
[4214:2830][2017-12-19T10:08:51]i329: Removed package dependency provider: Microsoft.DataTools.AnalysisServices, package: Microsoft.DataTools.AnalysisServices
[13C4:3020][2017-12-19T10:08:51]i000: MainViewModel.OnPackageActionProgress: Percent completed: 100, Overall progress: 100
[4214:2830][2017-12-19T10:08:51]i372: Session end, registration key: SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{058aacb1-dd61-42d2-951e-fc2d0b51c456}, resume: None, restart: None, disable resume: No
[4214:2830][2017-12-19T10:08:51]i330: Removed bundle dependency provider: {058aacb1-dd61-42d2-951e-fc2d0b51c456}
[4214:2830][2017-12-19T10:08:51]i352: Removing cached bundle: {058aacb1-dd61-42d2-951e-fc2d0b51c456}, from path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{058aacb1-dd61-42d2-951e-fc2d0b51c456}\
[4214:2830][2017-12-19T10:08:51]i371: Updating session, registration key: SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{058aacb1-dd61-42d2-951e-fc2d0b51c456}, resume: None, restart initiated: No, disable resume: No
[13C4:3020][2017-12-19T10:08:51]e000: MainViewModel.OnBundleAction: Bundle action failed: De aangevraagde metabestandsbewerking wordt niet ondersteund (0x800707D3)
[13C4:3020][2017-12-19T10:08:51]i399: Apply complete, result: 0x800707d3, restart: None, ba requested restart:  No
[13C4:2DC4][2017-12-19T10:09:07]i000: MainViewModel.OpenUrl: Opening url: C:\Users\GEBRUI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\SsdtSetup\SSDT-Setup-ENU_20171219090643.log
[13C4:2DC4][2017-12-19T10:10:35]i000: MainViewModel.OpenUrl: Opening url: 
C:\Users\GEBRUI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\SsdtSetup\SSDT-Setup-ENU_20171219090643.log
```

I have installed SQL Server Management Studio 17, and then SQL Server 2017 shortly before.

-

Can anyone help with this?

Comment: I always have trouble with this tool unfortunately. It was a different error, but here's my guide on how i installed it successfully bit by bit, You could try this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46421619/ssdt-installation-issue-failed-to-execute-exe-package/47645278#47645278

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I get to step 3, don't get a repair button. But I do note that only SQL Server Database was ticked, but none of the others (SSAS, SSIS, SSRS). Will try installing per part.

Comment: Could it have to do with the order of installation? SSManagement Studio --> SQL 2017 --> SSData Tools

Comment: Not sure - if you google it you'll find tales of woe. It's normally more to do with any prior install of Visual Studio

Comment: Answer is simple. After 24hrs try i got to know few visual studio 2017 components are missing. After installing the components run SSDT setup it will work.

Answer (score 3):

I got this attempting to install SSDT to Visual Studio 2019 (the only version of VS I have installed).  Fixed by telling SSDT to install the standalone Visual Studio 2017 option, and installed the extension "SQL Server Integration Services Projects" in Visual Studio 2019.

Answer (score 2):

I was getting the exact same error.  I had to repair my instance of Visual Studio Professional 2017 as that is where I was installing the tools.  After repairing that instance, had no problems with setting up SSDT.  Luckily I had just installed Visual Studio so I didn't lose any configuration.

Comment: Same error, fired up installer per Tim.  Saw that I had a VS 2017 update paused!  Clicked resume, let it finish, and SSDT installed.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/repair-visual-studio

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me, was to restart the computer and restart the installation of SSDT.

I installed Visual studio within the SSDT setup.

Answer (score 1):

Download and install the following `.vsix` files from Microsoft(i got these link from log):

- Microsoft.DataTools.IntegrationServices: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=871369
- Microsoft.DataTools.AnalysisServices: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=870525
- Microsoft.DataTools.ReportingServices: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=870526

Comment: Microsoft.DataTools.AnalysisServices link is incorrect, there is one available on Visual Studio Marketplace: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ProBITools.MicrosoftAnalysisServicesModelingProjects

Comment: How do I get it to install for visual studio 2017 instead of 2015?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but what worked for me was to right click on the SSDT installer (download it to your laptop/PC instead of running it from your browser) and run it as an administrator. I was lucky enough to get it to work without any other steps.

Comment: That really helps!! I tried so many ways above and only this easy one works..

Comment: ha ha ! I over complicated this until I saw your comment. Thanks much.

Answer (score 0):

In my case  SSISOneDesigner2014.msi was giving me an error to download in the log, and the only workaround was executing the **offline** SSDT install since I've already had a Visual Studio 2017 instance, executing

```
SSDT-Setup-ENU.exe /layout c:\<filepath>
```

(Where *filepath* is  any location you want to download installer files.)

Then, manually download SSISOneDesigner2014.msi and copy in `c:\<filepath>\payload`

After that execute the following:

```
SSDT-Setup-ENU.exe /install
```

This correctly installed the rest of the components.