# How do I get the rdlc report designer to work in Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: reporting-services, visual-studio-2017, sql-server-data-tools, designer, vsix

The designer is not working for reports in my project. I am using visual studio enterprise 2017. Most sites say that the solution is to install it by using this link "https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SqlReportingServices.MicrosoftRdlcReportDesignerforVisualStudio-18001" but that just takes me to a 404 error page. Is there an updated installer for this?

I have also tried to install the SSDT but am getting this error"

> [3438:197C][2018-07-13T10:42:08]e000: MainViewModel.OnBundleAction: Bundle action failed: The requested metafile operation is not supported (0x800707D3)

I tried installing them individually using the separate .vsix files from this [Error when installing SSDT (SQL Server Data Tools)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47884612/error-when-installing-ssdt-sql-server-data-tools/50596106#50596106) but it all states that "This extension is not installable on any currently installed products." The log below shows that it is not able to find my Visual Studio 2017 and is trying to install on 2015. I am not sure what to do now... help please

> 13-Jul-18 11:01:59 AM - Microsoft VSIX Installer 13-Jul-18 11:01:59 AM
>   - ------------------------------------------- 13-Jul-18 11:01:59 AM - Initializing Install... 13-Jul-18 11:02:00 AM - Extension Details...
>   13-Jul-18 11:02:00 AM -   Identifier         :
>   717ad572-c4b7-435c-c166-c2969777f718 13-Jul-18 11:02:00 AM -  Name
>   : Microsoft Reporting Services Projects 13-Jul-18 11:02:00 AM -
>     Author             : Microsoft 13-Jul-18 11:02:00 AM -  Version
>   : 1.23 13-Jul-18 11:02:00 AM -    Description        : The Microsoft RDL
>   report designer, projects and wizards for creating professional
>   reports. This package provides support for the .rptproj type and is
>   designed for the most recent versions of Microsoft Reporting Services.
>   13-Jul-18 11:02:00 AM -   Locale             : en-US 13-Jul-18 11:02:00
>   AM -  MoreInfoURL        :  13-Jul-18 11:02:00 AM -   InstalledByMSI
>   : False 13-Jul-18 11:02:00 AM -   SupportedFrameworkVersionRange :
>   [0.0,2147483647.2147483647] 13-Jul-18 11:02:00 AM -  13-Jul-18
>   11:02:08 AM -     SignatureState     : ValidSignature 13-Jul-18 11:02:08
>   AM -  SignedBy           : Microsoft Corporation 13-Jul-18 11:02:08 AM
>   -     Certificate Info   :  13-Jul-18 11:02:08 AM -       ------------------------------------------------------- 13-Jul-18
>   11:02:08 AM -         [Subject]       : CN=Microsoft Corporation, OU=OPC,
>   O=Microsoft Corporation, L=Redmond, S=Washington, C=US 13-Jul-18
>   11:02:08 AM -         [Issuer]        : CN=Microsoft Code Signing PCA 2010,
>   O=Microsoft Corporation, L=Redmond, S=Washington, C=US 13-Jul-18
>   11:02:08 AM -         [Serial Number] :
>   33000001FC5DB8191027A666C10000000001FC 13-Jul-18 11:02:08 AM -        [Not
>   Before]    : 06-Oct-17 2:26:08 AM 13-Jul-18 11:02:08 AM -         [Not
>   After]     : 06-Oct-18 2:26:08 AM 13-Jul-18 11:02:08 AM -
>         [Thumbprint]    : 5E940B33DEAE5945F506ADAB946A997867A40FEF 13-Jul-18
>   11:02:08 AM -  13-Jul-18 11:02:08 AM -    Supported Products : 
>   13-Jul-18 11:02:08 AM -       Microsoft.VisualStudio.Community 13-Jul-18
>   11:02:08 AM -             Version : [15.0.26510,16.0) 13-Jul-18 11:02:08 AM - 
>   13-Jul-18 11:02:08 AM -   References         :  13-Jul-18 11:02:08 AM -
>         ------------------------------------------------------- 13-Jul-18
>   11:02:08 AM -         Identifier   : BAB64743-DA65-4501-B3A3-A73171C73D77
>   13-Jul-18 11:02:08 AM -       Name         : Microsoft BI Shared
>   Components for Visual Studio 13-Jul-18 11:02:08 AM -      Version      :
>   [4.0.1,4.99) 13-Jul-18 11:02:08 AM -      MoreInfoURL  :  13-Jul-18
>   11:02:08 AM -         Nested       : Yes 13-Jul-18 11:02:08 AM -  13-Jul-18
>   11:02:08 AM - Signature Details... 13-Jul-18 11:02:08 AM -    Extension
>   is signed with a valid signature. 13-Jul-18 11:02:08 AM -  13-Jul-18
>   11:02:08 AM - Searching for applicable products... 13-Jul-18 11:02:08
>   AM - Found installed product - Microsoft Visual Studio Professional
>   2015 13-Jul-18 11:02:08 AM - Found installed product - Microsoft
>   Visual Studio Community 2015 13-Jul-18 11:02:08 AM - Found installed
>   product - Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 Shell (Integrated) 13-Jul-18
>   11:02:08 AM - Found installed product - Global Location 13-Jul-18
>   11:02:08 AM - Found installed product - ssms 13-Jul-18 11:02:08 AM -
>   VSIXInstaller.NoApplicableSKUsException: This extension is not
>   installable on any currently installed products.    at
>   VSIXInstaller.App.InitializeInstall(Boolean isRepairSupported)    at
>   VSIXInstaller.App.InitializeInstall()    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvoke()    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()

I have also tried this installer [here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ProBITools.MicrosoftReportProjectsforVisualStudio)
with error "The extention is not installable on any currently installed products."

This is the log:

> 16-Jul-18 10:53:57 AM - Microsoft VSIX Installer 16-Jul-18 10:53:57 AM
>   - ------------------------------------------- 16-Jul-18 10:53:57 AM - Initializing Install... 16-Jul-18 10:53:58 AM - Extension Details...
>   16-Jul-18 10:53:58 AM -   Identifier         :
>   717ad572-c4b7-435c-c166-c2969777f718 16-Jul-18 10:53:58 AM -  Name
>   : Microsoft Reporting Services Projects 16-Jul-18 10:53:58 AM -
>     Author             : Microsoft 16-Jul-18 10:53:58 AM -  Version
>   : 1.23 16-Jul-18 10:53:58 AM -    Description        : The Microsoft RDL
>   report designer, projects and wizards for creating professional
>   reports. This package provides support for the .rptproj type and is
>   designed for the most recent versions of Microsoft Reporting Services.
>   16-Jul-18 10:53:58 AM -   Locale             : en-US 16-Jul-18 10:53:58
>   AM -  MoreInfoURL        :  16-Jul-18 10:53:58 AM -   InstalledByMSI
>   : False 16-Jul-18 10:53:58 AM -   SupportedFrameworkVersionRange :
>   [0.0,2147483647.2147483647] 16-Jul-18 10:53:58 AM -  16-Jul-18
>   10:54:06 AM -     SignatureState     : ValidSignature 16-Jul-18 10:54:06
>   AM -  SignedBy           : Microsoft Corporation 16-Jul-18 10:54:06 AM
>   -     Certificate Info   :  16-Jul-18 10:54:06 AM -       ------------------------------------------------------- 16-Jul-18
>   10:54:06 AM -         [Subject]       : CN=Microsoft Corporation, OU=OPC,
>   O=Microsoft Corporation, L=Redmond, S=Washington, C=US 16-Jul-18
>   10:54:06 AM -         [Issuer]        : CN=Microsoft Code Signing PCA 2010,
>   O=Microsoft Corporation, L=Redmond, S=Washington, C=US 16-Jul-18
>   10:54:06 AM -         [Serial Number] :
>   33000001FC5DB8191027A666C10000000001FC 16-Jul-18 10:54:06 AM -        [Not
>   Before]    : 06-Oct-17 2:26:08 AM 16-Jul-18 10:54:06 AM -         [Not
>   After]     : 06-Oct-18 2:26:08 AM 16-Jul-18 10:54:06 AM -
>         [Thumbprint]    : 5E940B33DEAE5945F506ADAB946A997867A40FEF 16-Jul-18
>   10:54:06 AM -  16-Jul-18 10:54:06 AM -    Supported Products : 
>   16-Jul-18 10:54:06 AM -       Microsoft.VisualStudio.Community 16-Jul-18
>   10:54:06 AM -             Version : [15.0.26510,16.0) 16-Jul-18 10:54:06 AM - 
>   16-Jul-18 10:54:06 AM -   References         :  16-Jul-18 10:54:06 AM -
>         ------------------------------------------------------- 16-Jul-18
>   10:54:06 AM -         Identifier   : BAB64743-DA65-4501-B3A3-A73171C73D77
>   16-Jul-18 10:54:06 AM -       Name         : Microsoft BI Shared
>   Components for Visual Studio 16-Jul-18 10:54:06 AM -      Version      :
>   [4.0.1,4.99) 16-Jul-18 10:54:06 AM -      MoreInfoURL  :  16-Jul-18
>   10:54:06 AM -         Nested       : Yes 16-Jul-18 10:54:06 AM -  16-Jul-18
>   10:54:06 AM - Signature Details... 16-Jul-18 10:54:06 AM -    Extension
>   is signed with a valid signature. 16-Jul-18 10:54:06 AM -  16-Jul-18
>   10:54:06 AM - Searching for applicable products... 16-Jul-18 10:54:08
>   AM - Found installed product - Microsoft Visual Studio Professional
>   2015 16-Jul-18 10:54:08 AM - Found installed product - Microsoft
>   Visual Studio Community 2015 16-Jul-18 10:54:08 AM - Found installed
>   product - Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 Shell (Integrated) 16-Jul-18
>   10:54:08 AM - Found installed product - Global Location 16-Jul-18
>   10:54:08 AM - Found installed product - ssms 16-Jul-18 10:54:08 AM -
>   VSIXInstaller.NoApplicableSKUsException: This extension is not
>   installable on any currently installed products.    at
>   VSIXInstaller.App.InitializeInstall(Boolean isRepairSupported)    at
>   VSIXInstaller.App.InitializeInstall()    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvoke()    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()

Comment: Did you install this? https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ProBITools.MicrosoftReportProjectsforVisualStudio

Comment: I have tried that and keep getting the error that the extention is not installable on any currently installed products.

Comment: Is your VS instance updated to latest version?

Comment: I have checked and it is the latest version