# Install SSDT for Visual Studio 2017 community fails on recursion too deep

Tags: installation, visual-studio-2017, sql-server-data-tools

"Setup Failed" Recursion too deep; stack overflowed 0x800703E9.

I have windows 10 and newest visual studio version.  I have tried rebooting to make sure I have as many resources as possible.  I have 4g ram.

Comment: Refer - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46421619/ssdt-installation-issue-failed-to-execute-exe-package/47645278

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SSDT installation issue (Failed to execute EXE package.)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46421619/ssdt-installation-issue-failed-to-execute-exe-package)

Answer (score 8):

If the SSDT installer gives you multiple instances of Visual Studio to choose from, try the "new" option.

I ran into this problem trying to install SSDT 15.8.1 on Windows Server 2012 R2 with the latest version of Visual Studio 2017 (v15.8.6) already installed.  The SSDT installer gave me 2 options in a dropdown box.

> Install tools to this Visual Studio 2017 instance:
>
> - Visual Studio 2017
> - Install new SQL Server Data Tools for Visual Studio 2017

When I chose the first option:  Visual Studio 2017 (presumably the existing instance), I ran into the cryptic "recursion too deep" error.  I installed the SSRS extension for VS (as suggested by others on Stack Overflow) and tried running the SSDT installer again for the existing Visual Studio 2017 instance.  I got the same "recursion" error.

I tried one more time, but this time chose the 'Install new SQL Server Data Tools for Visual Studio 2017' option.  This time the install process completed!

Comment: Removing existing SSDT instances (installed as part of VS 2017 installation) did not correct the issue for me. Only installing to a "new" instance worked.

Answer (score 3):

Apparently there is an installer inconsistency between the latest versions of SSDT and Visual Studio. The suggested fix is to start with a previous installation of Visual Studio 2017, install the latest SSDT on top of that, and then upgrade Visual Studio. This is a very time consuming fix. It appears this is only necessary for the SSIS components - the SSAS and SSRS pieces are available as Extensions within VS, and I believe they still install successfully from there.

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/258117/ssdt-failed-to-install-vs-2017-pro-1572.html

Answer (score 0):

Please re-run the VS community 2017 installer or go to Control Panel-Programs and Features, uninstall the previous SSDT version for VS 2017, then re-install it, you can have a look at [this similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46421619/ssdt-installation-issue-failed-to-execute-exe-package).

If this issue persists, please use http://aka.ms/vscollect to gather the installation logs and find vslogs.zip under the %temp% folder, then upload the file to Onedrive and share the link here.

Comment: Ok, so I got the setup to work.  Uninstalled anything that looked like data tools and steps from the link you sent.  It took well over and hour rebooting after each step.  The original problem is exactly the same as it was before, i open up reports created and modified in Visual Studio 2013 and it opens the report but if I try to save it, preview it or build it I get an Unknown Version 9.0.  I have been unable to find any answer other than install data tools and this will be the 3rd time I've tried to install it in different ways to get it to recognize and update these reports.

Comment: I don't see how this is an install issue. If repairing didn't fix it, it's likely a bug in the implementation. I recommend cross-posting or tagging as a SQL issue (I do see you have "ssdt" tagged, but should add more SQL-related tags).

Comment: @billpennock, it seems your issue is solved, right? If so, could you please add a reply with your solution and mark it, that will help other community members to easier search, thanks in advance.

Comment: I gave up and went another direction.  The original problem was getting old rdl to open and I finally reverted back to a 2013 visual studio.  Sorry Sara, I didn't see your request till just now

Answer (score 0):

You should uninstall the current version of SSDT before install a new version.
If your computer have some pages blocked, you could download the specific version offline installer (Download the header, then use SSDT-Setup.exe /layout [Folder]) for the former version and new version of SSDT.

Answer (score 0):

How I got past it:

1. Uninstall the Visual Studio extensions for Reporting Services (and Analysis Services) projects in case if you going to select them during SSDT set up.  Note: remember to run VS as administrator to do the uninstall.
2. Reboot VS2017 (just out of general principle.)