# how to find SSDT-Setup-ENU.exe file

Tags: installation, sql-server-data-tools

I am looking at the problem that [Richard Tompsett : SSDT installation issue (Failed to execute EXE package)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46421619/ssdt-installation-issue-failed-to-execute-exe-package) had.  The answer in that question was to copy the SSDT-Setup-ENU.exe file in a temporary directory.

But I don't find the file "SSDT-Setup-ENU.exe" anywhere on my pc.

Can you help me please?

Thank you in advance.

Louise Messier

Comment: Hi, I think the problem is that you can't install ssdt and you can't find the exe to move into the temporary folder, thinking about it, you might have the 2017 version which is just called SSDTSetup.exe, which might explain why you can't find "SSDT-Setup-ENU.exe"

Answer (score 2):

If you want to download SSDT, the download page is:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt?view=sql-server-2017

Annoyingly, there are a couple of versions you can choose from.

If you want to use and already have installed:

- Visual Studio 2015, download from https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=863440
- Visual Studio 2017, download from: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=871368

If you don't have Visual Studio installed and need Visual Studio, you can either download Visual Studio 2017 community from:

https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/

and then download SSDT from one of the two links above.

If you don't have or don't want the full version of visual studio you can download the VS Shell version, which is a cut-down version of visual studio from the two links above, they will download and install the vs shell as well as ssdt.

If you specifically want "SSDT-Setup-ENU.exe" then that is the visual Studio 2015 version, the 2017 version was renamed "SSDTSetup.exe", no idea why.

If this is for a new project, I personally would just go and download Visual Studio community 2017 (if I needed it) and then get the 2017 version of SSDT:

https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=863440

Hope it helps!

ed