# Latest SSDT-BI won't install in Visual Studio 2017 15.7.5

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2017, ssdt-bi

Just upgraded my Visual Studio 2017 to version 15.7.5,  Then got [latest SSDT-BI standalone installer](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=875613).

However running that installer failed (the installer displayed the message, "Setup Failed, unknown error") and totally borked my VS installation.  Only remedy was to install a stand-alone version of VS using the download.

Any ideas/fixes?

Key section of log:

> Error 0x80131509: Process returned error: 0x80131509 Error 0x80131509:
>   Failed to execute EXE package. Error 0x80131509: Failed to configure
>   per-machine EXE package. MainViewModel.OnPackageAction: Install
>   Completed for package SQL Server Analysis Services (id:  Applied
>   execute package: Microsoft.DataTools.AnalysisServices, result:
>   0x80131509, restart: None Error 0x80131509: Failed to execute EXE
>   package.

I can't post the whole log from work (firewall restrictions).

Comment: How did you know that the installation failed? Was there maybe some error message that you forgot to mention? Maybe a conflict with some C++ 2015 redistributable? Give us a hint.

Comment: I know because at the end of the setup, it displayed the message: "Setup Failed, unknown error."  Also because the to-be-installed components were not installed.  Tried it again after a reboot.  Same result.

Comment: I don't believe that "unknown error" was the only information. If it was, then I have no idea.

Comment: The install also produced a log file, which was not helpful either.

Comment: I can post the whole log file.  Maybe you'll see something I missed.  Take me a little while, but I'll post it asap.

Comment: Did you research on the internet? Have you found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46421619/ssdt-installation-issue-failed-to-execute-exe-package)?

Comment: Yup. first place I went to!  The link you posted predates the release with the problem.  I had previously, successfully, installed VS and SSDT-BI.  It is only after the latest  update that the problem surfaced.

Comment: I suppose that it's a development machine and you have installed SSMS too. I had a similar problem that I solved uninstalling SSMS (and other components, C++ Resdistributables that were mentionned in the log), installing SSDT, then re-installing SSMS (and repairing VS).

Comment: Yeah, hoping to avoid that (lose a couple of hours) but there may be no other way

Comment: Got it!  Had to extract the files as per your link, then install only SSIS.  Maybe brave enough to test the others.

Comment: Glad to hear that! :-)