# Why SSDT installation process stop with the error 0x80070001?

Tags: sql-server-data-tools, ssdt-bi, ssdt-2019

[3884:3870][2022-02-19T01:38:46]e000: Error 0x80070001: Process returned error: 0x1

[3884:3870][2022-02-19T01:38:46]e000: Error 0x80070001: Failed to execute EXE package.

[346C:3470][2022-02-19T01:38:46]e000: Error 0x80070001: Failed to configure per-machine EXE package.

How to solve this error?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46421619/ssdt-installation-issue-failed-to-execute-exe-package

Comment: Thank you very much. Able to fix the issue through this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SSDT installation issue (Failed to execute EXE package.)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46421619/ssdt-installation-issue-failed-to-execute-exe-package)

Answer (score 0):

One of the fast solutions is installing Visual Studio and reinstalling SSDT again

Answer (score 0):

Solution at https://en.dirceuresende.com/blog/como-corrigir-erro-na-instalacao-do-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt-2017-setup-failed-incorrect-function-0x80070001/, using option "REPAIR".

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22000.795]
(c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\WINDOWS\system32>cd Downloads
The system cannot find the path specified.

C:\WINDOWS\system32>cd C:\Users\jmont\Downloads

C:\Users\jmont\Downloads>dir
 Volume in drive C is OS
 Volume Serial Number is E6C1-BFB7

 Directory of C:\Users\jmont\Downloads

08/08/2022  02:53 PM    <DIR>          .
08/08/2022  03:13 PM    <DIR>          ..    
08/08/2022  02:30 PM       552,785,944 Microsoft.DataTools.IntegrationServices.exe
08/08/2022  02:53 PM       957,052,968 SSDT-Setup-ENU.exe
               2 File(s)  1,509,838,912 bytes
               3 Dir(s)  871,865,147,392 bytes free

C:\Users\jmont\Downloads>vs_sql.exe --layout C:\SSTD2017 --lang en-us
'vs_sql.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\jmont\Downloads>SSDT-Setup-ENU.exe --layout C:\SSTD2017 --lang en-us
```

For Visual Studio 2017, I had to go to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/previous-releases-of-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt-and-ssdt-bi?view=sql-server-ver16 and download it from the link below:

SSDT for VS 2017 (standalone installer)
[Download SSDT for Visual Studio 2017 (15.9.10)](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2192400)

That was how I downloaded `SSDT-Setup-ENU.exe`.

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar type of error, then I found you have to edit your 2017 version with Visual Studio installer and need to add this below toolset.

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7svEZ.png]

Then you can retry to install SSDT tool, this time you will able to install it without this error !